# How to remove default text in dynamically textbox

Tags: asp.net, focus, dynamically-generated

I generate dynamically textbox in asp.net and set default text on it. Now, I’d like to clear textbox when it first comes into focus but if user don’t type any things, show default text again.

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textName;
    textName = new TextBox();
    textName.Text = "mail";
    TextBox textName2;
    textName2 = new TextBox();
    textName2.Text = "tel";
    string divContect = ControlRenderer(divTextBox);
    divTextBox.InnerHtml = divContect + ControlRenderer(textName) + "&nbsp;&nbsp" + ControlRenderer(textName2) + "<br/><br/>";

}

public string ControlRenderer(Control control)
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    control.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(writer));
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnTestTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
if (testTextBox.Text.Equals("Type here...", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        testTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }  
}
private void OnTestTextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testTextBox.Text))
    {
        testTextBox.Text = "Type here...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript with onblur and onfocus events.

Hope this will help you.

Try this please:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textName;
        textName = new TextBox();
        textName.ID = "textName";
        textName.Text = "mail";
        textName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        SetPromptText(textName);

        TextBox textName2;
        textName2 = new TextBox();
        textName2.ID = "textName2";
        textName2.Text = "tel";
        textName2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        SetPromptText(textName2);

        string divContect = ControlRenderer(divTextBox);
        divTextBox.InnerHtml = divContect + ControlRenderer(textName) + "&nbsp;&nbsp" + ControlRenderer(textName2);
    }

    public string ControlRenderer(Control control)
    {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        control.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(writer));
        return writer.ToString();
    }

    private void SetPromptText(TextBox textBox)
    {
        string onFocusAction = "if (this.value == \"{0}\") {{ this.value = \"\"; this.style.color = \"black\"; }} ";
        string onBlurAction = " if (this.value == \"\") {{ this.value = \"{0}\"; this.style.color = \"gray\"; }} else this.style.color = \"black\";";
        onBlurAction = string.Format(onBlurAction, textBox.Text);
        onFocusAction = string.Format(onFocusAction, textBox.Text);
        textBox.Attributes["onblur"] = onBlurAction;
        textBox.Attributes["onfocus"] = onFocusAction;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, It's works when I change all of {0}.value to this.value.

Comment: Another problem: I set default color of input gray and when user typed mail and telephone, color of input change to black, but colors don’t change black.
I add this code in Button1_Click method:
textName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray; 
and add this code in onFocusAction:
this.style.color=\"#000\"; but It's not work.

Comment: Ok,
I've changed SetPromptText to display default text in gray, and to turn forecolor to black whene users enter text.
Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: thanks but I find a better way for that:
            string place = "tel";
            place = string.Format(place, textBox.ID, textBox.Text);
            textBox.Attributes["placeholder"] = place;